# Syslog and daily files in C

Tags: c, linux, logging, syslog

I configured /etc/syslog.conf:

```
local0.debug /custom/path/log/app.log
```

so that syslog logs to a custom log file.

```
openlog("app", LOG_PID, LOG_LOCAL0);
```

Now I would also like syslog to create a different file each day, e.g.:

/custom/path/log/20210204_app.log

/custom/path/log/20210205_app.log

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use logrotate and configure /etc/logrotate.d/apt with your file and policies.
Something like this would do the job.

```
/custom/path/log/app.log {
  rotate 12
  daily
  missingok
  notifempty
}
```

For more look here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-logfiles-with-logrotate-on-ubuntu-16-04.